# How can I override template file from non magento core modules?

Tags: magento2

I have installed modules on **Magento 2**. I don't want to touch the module file. Is it possible to override that third-party module's template file from my **Custom Module**?

Comment: Yes you can in your desing folder can you post your code and name of your module

Answer (score 1):

Use **sequence** in your `module.xml` in order to load phtml file from your custom module

> app/code/Custom/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Thirdparty_Module"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/thirdparty_module_action.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="third_party_block_name">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module::thirdparty_template.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override custom module's template by overriding it in your theme as follows : 
Copy it in your theme under the path `app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/Custom_Mymodule/templates/<path_to_template_file>`

```
Anshu : Your theme namespace
mytheme : Your theme name
Custom_Mymodule : Your module's name
```

and make required modifications. 
I hope this will help you.